# Grails - How to remove multiple params from controller

Tags: grails, parameters, controller, parameter-passing

Im new to grails and using version of 2.1.1

I have been working params for passing data from view to controller
ie I have submit URL to controller :

```
http://example.com/save?param1=one&param2=two&param3=three&param4=four
```

and then the URL will handle with save() in controller, I use it and I will passing some param into another view. Code like this

```
redirect action: "index", params:params
```

but when I success to redirect, all param is include (param1,param2, param3 & param4)

```
http://example.com/index?param1=one&param2=two&param3=three&param4=four
```

I just want to have param1 in my index view.
Currently I do this remove param using :

```
params.remove("param2")
params.remove("param3")
params.remove("param4")
```

Is there any simply way to remove multiple params in grails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need just one parameter, the easiest way will be creating a new object:

```
redirect action: "index", params: [param1: params.param1]
```

Comment: Thanks Igor Its very helpful :D

Answer (score 4):

Igor's answer is probably what you want, but you can remove multiple keys in one line with this:

```
['param1', 'param2', 'param3'].each { params.remove it }
```

or you can remove all but one with this:

```
params.keySet().asList().each { if ('param1' != it) params.remove(it) }
```

I'm using `asList()` to copy the set to avoid a ConcurrentModificationException